# Error Using $this when not in object context

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-8

Alguien puede ayudarme me sale este error al intentar guardar los datos de cargados de un formulario html.
Esto es utilizando el framework de Laravel 8

ERROR
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save
C:\pw_ci\pw_ci\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:971

CONTROLADOR

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Service;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Contact;
use App\Models\Recomendation;

class SiteController extends Controller
   

   public function contactsStore  (Request $request) {

         $request->validate([
           'name' => 'required',
           'last_name' => 'required',
           'email' => 'required',
           'cell_phone' => 'required',
           'message' => 'required',
           ]);

       Contact::save([
           'name'=> $request->input('name'),
           'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
           'email' => $request->input('email'),
           'cell_phone' => $request->input('cell_phone'),
           'message' => $request->input('message'),

       ]);

       return redirect()->route('sites.contact.index')
           ->with('Exito','Mensaje enviado
           con exito.');
   }

}
```

FORMULARIO ABREVIADO

```
<form class="form-email" action="/contact" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                @csrf
            </form>
```

RUTA DE ACCESO

`Route::post('/contact', [SiteController::class, 'contactsStore'])->name('contactsStore');`

Comment: Buen día, si estás en ambiente de desarrollo, ¿Podrías copiar y pegar el error completo? Parece ser que no es de ninguna de las secciones de código que has agregado. ¿Podrías agregar el controlador completo? Tal vez ahí está el error.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato acabo de agregar un poco mas el error y el controlador completo.

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionó, recuerda que al hacer preguntas siempre es mejor poner la información completa, eso reduce el tiempo de respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Genial @HeytalePazguato muchas gracias por tu ayuda...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Al parecer el error está en el método `save()`

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

1. Sustituye `save` por `make`
2. Asigna `Contact::make()` a una variable
3. Ejecuta el método `save` en la variable

De la siguiente forma:

```
$contacto = Contact::make([
    'name'=> $request->input('name'),
    'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
    'email' => $request->input('email'),
    'cell_phone' => $request->input('cell_phone'),
    'message' => $request->input('message'),
]);

$contacto->save();
```